# What is a hard core in inter particle potential?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, terminology, perturbation-theory, interactions

I am reading the book *A Modern Course in Statistical Physics* by Reichl. In it, there is the following statement

> The theory of interacting semi-classical fluids is also easily described by the Grand Canonical Ensemble. The inter particle potential has a hard core and weak interaction region so perturbation expansion in terms of the potential are not convergent.

Can somebody explain what this sentence is trying to convey?

Comment: A hard-core inter-particle potential is another word for a [hard-sphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_spheres) inter-particle potential, i.e. impenetrable spheres that cannot overlap in space, i.e. an infinite wall potential.

Comment: Is the perturbation expansion non convergent because of r^-n dependence of the potential?

Comment: I think it's because the hard-core potential is divergent ($\infty$ for $r<d$, where $d$ is the hard-core diameter and $0$ for $r \geq d$)

Comment: Could you refer us to the exact section of the book?

Comment: It is in the introduction and in the section about virial expansion in Chapter 6.